# Removing Headers from CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, header, export-csv

Need help removing headers from a CSV file. The tool the files are being imported into has very stringent requirements. The top row has to be *Title* then row 2 *date: 8/19/2019*. Row three should contain data with no headers.

Tried to import it back and drop the top row using [1..-1] notation as well as tried to bring the data in with a `Select-object -skip 1`. Still can't make it work.

Also tried writing the object array out to TXT but it only comes out as fields instead of being tab based like in CSV. Example:

Date: 
INfo: 
Field1:

```
get-content "c:\users\user123\documents\adh\_$(get-date (get-date).addDays($i) -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content "c:\users\user123\documents\adh\_$(get-date (get-date).addDays($i) -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"
```

The file still contains the headers even after I tried to remove them.

Comment: Is it possible that you could choose an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The file can be constructed after you get the .csv file that contains a field header record. The `csmem.csv` file has been produced, but has a header record. This will write the title and date on the first two (2) records, then append the .csv file without the header record.

```
"The Title" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\src\t\sf.csv" -Encoding ascii
(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') | Out-File -FilePath "C:\src\t\sf.csv" -Encoding ascii -Append
Get-Content -Path 'C:\src\t\csmem.csv' |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Out-File -FilePath "C:\src\t\sf.csv" -Encoding ascii -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a generated sample file:

```
> Get-Content .\_2019-08-19.csv
"COLA","ColB"
"Test1","Foo"
"Test2","Baz"
"Test3","Bar"
"Test4","Baz"
"Test5","Baz"
```

This script:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\08\20\SO_SO_57581085.ps1
## 
$i = 1
$BaseDir = 'C:\Users\user123\Documents\adh'
# $BaseDir = (gi .).FullName
$BaseName= '_{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-$i)

"Your Title`ndate: {0:M\/d\/yyyy}" -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-$i) | 
  Set-Content (Join-Path $BaseDir ($BaseName+'.txt')) # -Encoding if req.

Get-Content (Join-Path $BaseDir ($BaseName+'.csv')) | 
  Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Add-Content (Join-Path $BaseDir ($BaseName+'.txt')) # -Encoding if req.
```

Yields this result file:

```
> Get-Content .\_2019-08-19.txt
Your Title
date: 8/19/2019
"Test1","Foo"
"Test2","Baz"
"Test3","Bar"
"Test4","Baz"
"Test5","Baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your starting point is an *in-memory object array*, to be converted to CSV without headers.

To get a CSV representation without headers you needn't create an intermediate *file* with `Export-Csv` - simply pipe to `ConvertTo-Csv`, which produces an array of strings, whose first element - the header row - you can skip with `Select-Object -Skip 1`.

Your entire file can therefore be written via a single expandable here-string:

```
# Format the date string.
$i = 2 # sample value
$dateString = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays($i)

# The input object array
# $objArray = ...

# Use an expandable here-string to write the output file.
@"
Title
$dateString
$($objArray | ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-String)
"@ | Set-Content -NoNewline "c:\users\user123\documents\adh\_$dateString.txt"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> tried to import it back and drop the top row using [1..-1] notation

`[1..-1]` does *not* skip the first element of an array in PowerShell, because `1..-1` is a *range expression* that expands to the following list of indices: `1, 0, -1`; that is, you're extracting exactly *3* elements: the 2nd (`1`), the first (`0`), and the last one (`-1`).

> Also tried writing the object array out to TXT but it only comes out as fields instead of being tab based like in CSV. Example:

That sounds like you sent your in-memory object array to a `*.txt` file using something *other* than `Export-Csv`, which won't give you CSV output; it sounds like you used `>` or `Out-File`, where objects are formatted the same way they'd print to the console, which is a *for-display* format, not one suitable for programmatic processing.

> `get-content ....csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content ....txt`

That command *should* work, assuming that the input `*.csv` file was created with 
`Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation`.

If you didn't use `-NoTypeInformation`, use `-Skip 2`, i.e., skip an *additional* line, so as to skip the *type-annotation line* that `Export-Csv` - unfortunately - outputs as the 1st line by default.

Note: This counter-intuitive default behavior of `Export-Csv` in *Windows PowerShell* has been fixed in PowerShell *Core*.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file on a test environment, try to add **-NoTypeInformation** this might solve your problem.

*-NoTypeInformation* will remove the metadata, so be careful in the testing.

Comment: I think the `-NoTypeInformation` just removes that type header when exporting CSVs. I don't think it does anything to the actual CSV headers. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue by generating a test CSV like so:

`Get-Process | Select ProcessName, ID, SI | Export-CSV C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation`

What you've stumbled upon is an interesting aspect of the pipeline. I don't know the specifics of WHY it's doing what it's doing, but you have two ways of working around it automatically putting the headers back in the CSV:

1. Add -NoClobber to your Out-File:
   `Get-Content C:\temp\test.csv | Select -Skip 1 | Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\new.csv" -NoClobber`
   The caveat here is that it won't let you overwrite the file you've opened with Get-Content so you'll have to send it to a separate file
2. Or you can bypass the pipeline by storing the result of `Get-Content C:\temp\test.csv | Select -Skip 1` into a variable and then sending that variable to a regular Out-File call. This would let you overwrite the file.

Comment: It sounds like you think the OP's problem is an attempt to write back to the same file that is being read - it is not, because the command in the question writes to a _different_ file (`*.txt`). As for why: The pipeline _streams_ (processes input object by object), so the write command tries to write lines to a file that is _still open_, because the read command (`Get-Content`) hasn't finished reading it yet. A simple workaround is to enclose the `Get-Content` call in `(...)`, which forces reading _up front_: `(Get-Content ...) | ... | Set-Content ...`. Slight risk of data loss, though.